# “the top levels of government” -- why not "of THE government"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

Example taken from: [*Russia questions five suspects over Nemtsov killing*](http://news.yahoo.com/russia-holds-two-more-suspects-over-nemtsov-killing-081958813.html):

> However no information has emerged as to the possible motive the men could have had in killing the charismatic opposition leader. His allies believe his assassination was a hit ordered by **the top levels of government** determined to silence dissenters. The allegation has been strenuously denied.

Why not say *by the top levels of the government*? What do you think the difference would be?

Comment: This could be a regional difference.  The author (https://twitter.com/franblandy) works for L’Agence France-Presse.  AFP may have a different style than what I am used to (as an American).

Comment: @CoolHandLouis It's not just BrE... We would never use "the government" in this case, either.

Comment: @Catija You're right... it's not just BrE, so I retracted my prior comment.  However, I wouldn't go so far as to say that AmEng would *never* use "the government" in this case.

Comment: @Jasper A friend of mine actually tweeted Ms Blandy and gave her the link to this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... ordered by the top levels of **government** ...

The "missing" article is called *[zero article](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/zeroarticleterm.htm)*:

> Definition:
>
> An occasion in speech or writing where a noun or noun
>   phrase is not preceded by an article (a, an, or the).
>
> In general, the
>   zero article is used with proper nouns, mass nouns where the reference
>   is indefinite, and plural count nouns where the reference is
>   indefinite. Also, the zero article is generally used with means of
>   transport ("by plane") and common expressions of time and place ("at
>   midnight," "in jail")

1. The **indefinite** article *a* (or its phonetic variant *an*) is used to indicate:

   > - one of many -- *I  hope to meet **a** girl.*
   > - an unidentified thing (or person) -- *I  met **a** girl.*
2. The **definite** article *the* is used to indicate:

   > - an identified thing -- *I  met a girl at **the** dance.*
3. The **zero** article is used to indicate:

   > - generic plural nouns -- *I have met **girls** in the past.*
   > - uncountable nouns -- *I want to find **companionship**.*
   > - things in general -- *The dance is at **school**.*

It is quite normal for common nouns to use the *zero article* even in reference to a definite thing, especially as the object of prepositions. Everyone going to the dance knows **exactly which school** they will go to, but they have two options in talking about where the dance will be:

> *The dance is at **school**.*
>   *The dance is at **the** school.*

*Government* is one of these common nouns that leaves the writer this option:

> *... ordered by the top levels of **government***
>   *... ordered by the top levels of **the** government*

One rationale for this flexibility is that the context already makes the identity of this common noun so definite that the definite article is implied even when it is not expressed.

---

A partial list of common nouns that can **sometimes** be definite without the definite article:

> **Institutions**: church, college, prison, school, university & hospital
>   (except not hospital in US English) ... :
>   *I  met a girl at **school***, but **not**: *I  met a girl at dance.*
>
> **Places**: work, home, bed ... :
>   *I  met a girl at **home***.
>   but **not**:
>   *I  met a girl at dance.*
>
> **Meals**: breakfast, lunch, dinner ... :
>   *I  met a girl after **dinner***.
>   but **not**:
>   *I  met a girl after dance.*
>
> **Holidays**: Christmas, Easter, Hanukah, New Year ... :
>   *I  met a girl after **dinner***.
>   but **not**:
>   *I  met a girl after dance.*
>
> **Transportation**: bike, car, foot, plane, train ... :
>   *I  met a girl on **foot***.
>    but **not**:
>   *I  met a girl on dance floor.*

For more detailed information consult:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do something with 'jargon' and that's the reason, the journalist has not included the definite article before the word 'government' [However, I'm coming up with an example where 'the' is **used** in *such* sentence structure].

To prove this point, I'll bring in two references:

**Reference 1**:

David Marsh, Guardian Style, Guardian Books 2007 defines:

> "Leaving 'the' out often reads like jargon: say the conference agreed to do something, not 'conference agreed'; ***the government has to do, not 'government has to'***; the Super League (rugby), not 'Super League.'"

Taking this reference, I referred COCA, and was a bit *surprised*.

**Reference 2**:

`"....levels of government..."` returned 395 results. Examples:

> *"...had powerful supporters at the highest levels of government."*
>
> *"They relentlessly target the military, defense contractors and the highest levels of government."*
>
> *"The levels of government include: a) federal (both) b) provincial..."*

And so on...

On the other hand,

`"....levels of the government..."` returned 21 results. Examples:

> *"And so this is still being discussed at the top levels of the government."*
>
> *"Al Qaeda had been communicated directly to the highest levels of the government."*
>
> *"...perhaps even at the very highest levels of the government, who were making money off of this..."*

So to answer this question, I think it depends on the 'author's style'. If the author puts article, it might be to avoid the jargon (Guardian style) but if he does not use, it's *not incorrect*.

Answer (score -2):

Over
Brazen
Audacious

One gets the notion that the writer is either a non-native speaker or has a habit of poor word choice (seems like she learned her vocabulary from a thesaurus and not from lifelong use of the language) and awkward sentence construction. Given this, it's impossible to answer why she wrote what she did. And yes this is an answer and not a comment.

Comment: For me, in order for this to be a good stack-exchange type answer, the points you make need to be backed up with details why you think this is so.

Comment: I am aware tht the user has deleted their account and can no longer respond to clarifications.  But I find this answer beyond the pale. How this could have been awarded the bounty in preference to ScotM's answer is quite bizarre. No explanation, no supporting evidence, no reference just an anonymous user's opinion. Who is/was user6951?

Comment: One saving grace, the OP has now accepted ScotM's answer.